# How to reuse layout in android but at the same time use multiple ID?

Tags: android, android-layout, styles, android-xml, android-styles

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

In this website it introduce

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar"/>
```

to reuse layout, so I may code like this the problem is ,

```
<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
 android:id="@+id/bar_1"/>

<include layout="@layout/titlebar"
 android:id="@+id/bar_2"/>
```

if the titlebar is a linearlayout, and I would like to **get the textview inside titlebar**, how can I differenate between bar 1 and bar 2? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
// Get root View id from that include link
View yourLayout1 = findViewById(R.id.bar1); 
View yourLayout2 = findViewById(R.id.bar2); 

// Get text view contained inside the include file
TextView yourTextView1 = (TextView)(yourLayout1.findViewById( R.id.yourInnerTextview )); 
TextView yourTextView2 = (TextView)(yourLayout2.findViewById( R.id.yourInnerTextview ));
```

P.S: I haven't tested it but logically sounds good. So let me know if it works.

Comment: This does not work, because the yourLayout1 and yourLayout2 are null. The layout tag id does not work.

Comment: @Nicola Are you using `merge` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Look for a child view with the given id.  If this view has the given
 * id, return this view.
 *
 * @param id The id to search for.
 * @return The view that has the given id in the hierarchy or null
 */
public final View findViewById(int id) {
    if (id < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return findViewTraversal(id);
}
```

View Object also have findViewById function. And it only find the child . So you can firstly find the bar_1 or bar_2 , and then use the bar_1 Object or bar_2 Object's findViewById function to get the child view you want.